# Does using macros instead of functions make the binary bigger?

Tags: rust, macros

Will using macros result in having more machine instructions (and hence, the binary size) than using functions? I am asking because one of my macros that I use a lot became quite large so I started worrying. I have an impression that macros are copy-pasted as many times as I use them. Is that true?

I could test that myself, but it's a bit troublesome, also I wanted to hear what informed people would say. I am an absolute layman when it comes to assembly language, machine instructions and the like, so sorry if I wrote something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably yes, using macros instead of functions may make the binary bigger. But it depends on how your specific case compiles.

Macros are expanded before the compilation proceeds, so the result is like if you copied the code into every function where the macro is used. It is unlikely that the compiler can extract those pieces of code to some common place.

Functions usually exist only in one place and calling them jumps into that place. However, functions may get expanded (inlined) the same way as macros. But that happens only if the compiler decides that it is beneficial, or if you annotate the function with `#[inline(always)]`.

In general if you can achieve what you need with both function and macro, use function. Macros are useful for special cases that can not be achieved by functions. (Like creating custom syntax, or getting the line number of the call site...)

Comment: The intermediate syntax tree might be bigger (not necessarily), but I am not sure there is a general way to know how that impacts the binary, given how compilers work. A macro that expresses list comprehensions might expands as an optimized loop, etc. I agree about staying away from macros when possible.

Comment: True, I have modified the answer to be less definitive.